# How to setState response of API request in ReactJS with Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do you setState Axios response when you call API request by submitting form? I want to send form from / in POST method, and get API response, then redirect to /result page with API response.  My code is below and it raises

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>    This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function. in Home (at App.js:21)

After finishing handleSubmit, submitted stores true, but res is still initialized as {}, not storing API response. Even console.log(response) shows right response from API. I want to make a text classifier WEB service. I might have to use useEffect as warning says, but I am not sure. and don't know how to use it with form submission. Thank you.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/result">
            <Result />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function Home() {
  const useInput = initialValue => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)
    return {
      value, 
      setValue,
      reset: () => setValue(''),
      bind: {
        value,
        onChange: event => {setValue(event.target.value)}
      }
    }
  }

  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const {value: url, bind: bindUrl, reset: resetUrl} = useInput('')
  const {value: content, bind: bindContent, reset: resetContent} = useInput('')
  const [res, setRes] = useState({})

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict', {url:url, content:content}) // My API
    .then(response => {
      setSubmitted(true)
      console.log(response)
      setRes(response) // This doesn't work
    })
  }
  if (submitted) {
    return <Redirect push to={{
      pathname: '/result',
      state: {response: res}
    }}
    />
  }   
  return (
  <div>
    <h1>Send URL and Content</h1>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          URL:
          <input name="url" type="text" {...bindUrl} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          content:
          <input name="content" type="text" {...bindContent} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
  </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are redireting to other component if `submitted` is true, so after redirecting the component will be unmounted so that warning is displayed

Comment: what you want, you want to store the response and display something based on it??, if you are redirecting to other page then there is not point in storing the data

Comment: Yes, I want to send some text from /, and then displays response at /result. At first I tried to Redirect in handleSubmit, but it doesn't work. So, then I tried to store the response and redirect with stored response.

Comment: I guess there is a way to show /result page without storing response at / page before redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this snippet to your code

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(Object.values(response).length) {  // Here place an valid check to know if valid response is present
      setSubmitted(submitted => !submitted)
  }
}, [response])
```

And change your API call method as

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault()
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict', {url:url, content:content}) // My API
.then(response => {
  setRes(response)
})
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I add snippet in handleSubmit?

Comment: @NaokiWatanabe Yes

Comment: then it raises _React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function_

Comment: where are you placing the useEffect callbak, you have to place it at the top of the functional component

Comment: Thank you. Then, how to pass response into useEffect? response is given by axios promise chain.

Comment: you are already setting response to state using `setRes` which will be available in useEffect

Comment: I replaced response into res in useEffect (as I called ```const [res, setRes] = useState({})```), then I see _DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function transformRequest(data, headers) {
    normalizeHeaderName(headers, 'Accept');
    normalizeHeaderName(...<omitted>... } could not be cloned._

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution. Browser Back button also works.

```js
function Home() {
  const useInput = initialValue => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)
    return {
      value, 
      setValue,
      reset: () => setValue(''),
      bind: {
        value,
        onChange: event => {setValue(event.target.value)}
      }
    }
  }

  const {value: url, bind: bindUrl, reset: resetUrl} = useInput('')
  const {value: content, bind: bindContent, reset: resetContent} = useInput('')
  const history = useHistory()

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict', {url:url, content:content}) // My API
    .then(response => {
      history.push({pathname:'/result', state: response.data})
    })
  }
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history